# Is this T-SQL query correct?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

My code returns a data set, however I do not believe they are accurate and I'm a bit lost working with sub queries. Can someone look over my code. The problem I'm trying to solve is from advanced question from T-SQL 2012 book. The question tells me:

*Get the order ID, order date, customer ID, and company name for all orders that contain at least one item from the Condiments category.  Use the category name in your query.*

This is my code:

```
SELECT 
    o.orderid, o.orderdate, o.custid, c.companyname
FROM 
    Sales.Orders AS o
JOIN 
    Sales.OrderDetails AS od ON o.orderid = od.orderid
JOIN 
    Sales.Customers AS c ON o.custid = c.custid
WHERE  
    qty > 1
    (SELECT categoryname FROM
        Production.Categories    
        WHERE categoryname = N'Condiments');
```

My results:

```
orderid    orderdate            custid  companyname
-------------------------------------------------------
10248   2006-07-04 00:00:00.000 85      Customer ENQZT
10248   2006-07-04 00:00:00.000 85      Customer ENQZT
10249   2006-07-05 00:00:00.000 79      Customer FAPSM
10250   2006-07-08 00:00:00.000 34      Customer IBVRG
```

Table structure:

**Customers**:

```
Sales.Customers
(
     custid       INT          NOT NULL IDENTITY,
     companyname  NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
     contactname  NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     contacttitle NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)

PK custid
```

**Orders**:

```
Sales.Orders
(
    orderid        INT          NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    custid         INT          NULL,
    empid          INT          NOT NULL,
    orderdate      DATETIME     NOT NULL
)

PK orderid
FK custid
```

**Categories:**

```
Production.Categories
(
    categoryid   INT           NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    categoryname NVARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL,
    description  NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Categories PRIMARY KEY(categoryid)
);
```

**Orderdetails**:

```
Sales.OrderDetails
(
    orderid   INT           NOT NULL,
    productid INT           NOT NULL,
    unitprice MONEY         NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT DFT_OrderDetails_unitprice DEFAULT(0),
    qty       SMALLINT      NOT NULL
)
```

I'm wrecking my head as this must be a correlated query because the `Category` table shares no relationship with `Orders` or `Customers`. Much appreciated for all learning/teaching responses.

Comment: You should share the tables structure so we can know how the query should be built. Trying to guess the structure from your query is an unnecessary effort.

Comment: Your query is syntactically incorrect, so I'm surprised that it returns anything other than an error.

Comment: Hence the reason for asking for assistance. Apologies for not including table structure.

Comment: That's not your actual query, because it will not execute. It has a syntax error that would prevent it from doing so, and therefore cannot produce the results you indicate. So the answer to the question you asked is *No, this TSQL query is not correct*. Does that help?

Comment: Do you have a table structure for your Products table? The products table may have a relationship to the Categories table. This is how you bridge them all together.

Comment: If screen sharing were possible you could see that it does indeed execute.

Comment: Production.Products
(
  productid    INT          NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  productname  NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  supplierid   INT          NOT NULL,
  categoryid   INT          NOT NULL,
  unitprice    MONEY        NOT NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There we go, your query should include the Products table, something like this:

```
SELECT o.orderid, o.orderdate, o.custid, c.companyname
FROM Sales.Orders AS o
     JOIN Sales.OrderDetails AS od
     ON o.orderid = od.orderid
     JOIN Sales.Customers AS c
     ON o.custid = c.custid
     JOIN Production.Products d
     on od.ProductId = d.ProductId
     JOIN Production.Categories cat
     on cat.CategoryId = d.CategoryID
     and cat.categoryname = N'Condiments');
```

This may be enough to get you started.

Comment: Basiclsaac, much appreciated. Learning is a good thing and I suppose some questions rub folks the wrong way. I am upvoting because this will work however I was trying to stay within the context of the book chapter and use correlated query. Then again i'm also guided by the 'book' that joins work just as well with no loss in performance.

Comment: I see. No worries, you can still turn this into a correlated query. There are a few ways you can do this. This is a valid correlated query here:
    select o.orderid, o.orderdate, o.custid, (select c.companyname from     
    customers.c where o.custid = c.custid) CompanyName
    from sales.orders o  
Follow this trail to connect your orderdetails to your categories to your products via correlated subquery.

Comment: Thanks for the breadcrumbs to the solution. I kind of took on the 'advanced' problems from the book with the endstate being I learn more complex problems. If I had the knowledge and insight to help others I would as you have. Again, much appreciated as I've learned a bit more.

Comment: I support your efforts. IMO, it'd be a disservice to you to straight up do your homework. When we were learning this stuff there was no SO, and the only guy in the office that knew what he was doing was sick of all the questions, but eventually we all learned. I just got back from  Silicon Valley, and came back thinking "why aren't there any young Americans interested in being programmers?" These are great jobs full of challenges. Hang in there!